# In array formula, find last specific value up till each row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a Google Sheets in question. Here is a mocked version that you can copy or comment on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1szcfZt_CtE0Cd_evKJwN4enZE7JcmDFcw9XhoX-_mlw/edit?usp=sharing

The sheets comes with 2 columns, `Test number` and `Test result`. I'd like to use array formula to automatically fill column C whenever new tests are entered. The specification is that the number in column C should always refer to the last "Fail" test number up till each row. You can see the expected result in column E.

I can come up with many solutions that require a formula to be applied to each new cell, which I think is iterative approach. One example is in column G. The reason is that "up till the current row" can't be met with array formula. I tried `QUERY` function with no success. I know App Script can do this too, but that's not auto fill approach as well.

EDIT: Added a brute-force solution, which can only work with limit number of consecutive "Pass" results.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the screenshot for a solution using an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. Just to clarify, do you need to put that formula to every cell in column C or only C4? I'm looking for solution that only needs formula in C4 and automatically extend to new rows when new test result in column B is entered.